# How to do that after addeventlistener don't override css styles

Tags: javascript, textarea, addeventlistener

I have a textarea and 2 range,the second will work for created textarea
First user can input text and height of textarea increase or can delete and height of textarea decrease,
also user can choose font size and height of textarea increase depend of font size  and don't occur scroll

When I click on button create textarea and I want that the same functionality work for created textarea
but when I choose font size all css styles for that textarea override(background:'red',resize:'none'...) and also don't work the same way

I want the same function work for created textarea,that width still the same,don't change , and height change size depend of font size

https://jsfiddle.net/rmcuLjbh/4/

```
            input.id = 'inputText2';
            input.style.width = '150px';
            input.style.border = '1px solid';
            input.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
            input.style.resize = 'none';
            input.style.position = 'absolute';
            input.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

Comment: You could store the elms in an array when you create a new element. Then have a dropdown to select which textarea you want to change. So each time the button is clicked your essentially appending the element array with the id of the new element. **Note**: The function needs to know which ID to interact with in order to make just one function. So there has to be a way to identify this.

Comment: I know but It doesn't matter,my question about how to save css styles,because when i choose font size from range,my created textarea don't save css styles

Comment: I just want create textarea after onclick on button,with the same functonality what has  #inputText textarea